# Crop page from facing-page scan

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

Suppose I want to crop just the left pages from facing-page scans of a spiral notebook like the example below (from [Paolini.net](https://www.paolini.net/scan-130701-0016_eldestspiralboundpages19and18-pnet/)).

[image]

Is there a more robust way than simply dividing the image's width by half? For example, a smarter algorithm would detect the spiral binding and make that the right boundary and even exclude black area to the left of the page.

If there's a relatively easy way to do this with OpenCV or ImageMagick, I'd love to learn it.

Comment: "roboust" would depend on many things. lighting, changing book and hence binding types, page alignment...

Comment: Are you hoping its will work with different colour spiral bindings? Without spirals? With books bound some other way?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No, I'm just processing different pages of *one* notebook, so the images can be assumed to be similar, with slight variations. If the solution works on one, it should easily work on all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way in ImageMagick 6 with Unix scripting is to do the following:

```
Trim the image to remove most of the black on the sides

Scale the image down to 1 row, then scale up to 50 rows just for visualization

Threshold the scaled image so that you get the black region down the spine as the largest black region

Do connected components process to find the x coordinate of the largest black region

Crop the image according to the results from the connected components
```

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.jpg -fuzz 25% -trim +repage img_trim.png
```

[image]

```
convert img_trim.png -scale x1! -scale x50! -threshold 80% img_trim_x1.png
```

[image]

```
centx=$(convert img_trim_x1.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | \
grep "gray(0)" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d, -f1)

convert img_trim.png -crop ${centx}x+0+0 img_result.jpg
```

Data from connected components has the following header and structure:

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
```

So head -n 1 gets the first black, i.e. gray(0) region which is the largest (sorted largest to smallest). The awk prints the 3rd entry, centroid, and the cut gets the x component.

[image]

If using ImageMagick 7, then change `convert` to `magick`

If you want to exclude the binders in the middle, then use the x-offset of the bounding box from the connected components listing:

```
convert img_trim.png -scale x1! -scale x50! -threshold 80% img_trim_x1.png
leftcenterx=$(convert img_trim_x1.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | \
grep "gray(0)" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d+ -f2 | cut -d+ -f1)
convert img_trim.png -crop ${leftcenterx}x+0+0 img_result2.jpg
```

[image]

If you want just both pages, then we can find the white regions, i.e. gray(255) and crop them according to the width and x offset from the bounding boxes.

```
convert img.jpg -fuzz 25% -trim +repage img_trim.png
convert img_trim.png -scale x1! -scale x50! -threshold 80% img_trim_x1.png
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
bboxArr=(`convert img_trim_x1.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | \
grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`)
IFS=$OLDIFS
num=${#bboxArr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
WW=`echo ${bboxArr[$i]} | cut -dx -f1`
Xoff=`echo ${bboxArr[$i]} | cut -d+ -f2`
convert img_trim.png -crop ${WW}x+${Xoff}+0 img_result3_$i.jpg
done
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice work! Not at a computer but I think you have inter-twiddled `xcent` and `centx`.